# Is there any way of adding custom variables to Controls in c#?

Tags: c#, variables, controls, overloading

I have multiple RichTextBoxes and I would like to store a boolean on them so I can access it for each of them. Is there any way?

I tried using the Extensions Methods, like I do to have more overloads for AppendText, but I had no luck there.

Comment: Simply derive your own class from RichTextBox.  You can add any properties you need.

Comment: Is this for WinForms, WPF or Web?

Answer (score 0):

You can add whatever property you want. If you need to be able to change it at design time (from property editor) you just have to decorate with with the Browsable attribute.

Other attributes that might help:

CategoryAttribute - this attribute indicates in wich category of your property grid will reside your property.

DescriptionAttribute - this attribute adds a description for your property that will apear as a text description in the bottom of the property grid.

BUT  if you cannot modify existing control, you must use inheritance (inherit in your case from RichTextBox). If the class is sealed then I would create another control that decorates current one (the decorator pattern) and add a new property on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Tag Property. Its defined on Control so is available for all controls including your RichTextBox [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Quick simple solution (maybe not as elegant), but for the sake of simplicity, you can just create hidden fields using `@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.MyField1Bool).` That is if you are posting back to the server. You'd need to create the extra boolean fields to your ViewModel of course.

Also, just in case you are planning to use javascript to access these booleans. You should have a look at data attributes, for example:

```
<input type="text" data-flag="true"/>
```

These are easy to access in javascript. And in Razor syntax you just add them as attributes.